# Why does Akra-Bazzi need that toll-function g is bounded?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Following up on [vonbrand's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/10373/98) I want to write a small document about stronger master theorems for our students, one of which is the Akra-Bazzi theorem. I have copied the theorem from their paper [1] and found -- besides a small notational confusion² -- the following problem.

The authors require (emphasis mine):

> $g(x)$ is defined for real values $x$, and is **bounded**, positive and nondecreasing function
>   $\forall x \geq 0$

Here, $g$ is the toll function, that is the recurrence has the form

$\qquad\displaystyle T(n) = g(n) + \sum_{i=1}^k a_i T\bigl(\lfloor n b_i^{-1} \rfloor\bigr)$.

Now, at the end of their paper (p209) they give multiple examples for applying their result and they use functions in $\Omega(n)$ which are clearly *not* bounded.

From skimming the proof they mainly seem to require that integrals of the form

$\qquad\displaystyle \int_a^b \frac{g(x)}{x^{p+1}} dx$

have finite values. So, requiring $g$ to be bounded *on every compact interval* might be sufficient; I did not work through the proof in detail. Is it possible they mean that?

My question is: How should the Akra-Bazzi theorem be stated so that it is consistent with proof *and* examples?

---

1. [On the solution of linear recurrence equations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A%3A1018373005182) by M. Akra and L. Bazzi (1998)
2. They require $a_i \in R^{*+}$. Is this some notation I don't know, or a typo? I assume the intended meaning is $(0,\infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Tom Leighton's notes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.1636&rep=rep1&type=pdf), referenced from the Wikipedia article.
His notes apparently have less typos then the original paper. The condition he demands of $g$ is having *polynomial growth*, which means that if you scale the argument by a constant, then the amount that the function scales is also bounded by a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Nicest version of the Akra-Bazzi theorem I've seen is the one in Lehman, Leighton, Meyer ["Mathematics for Computer Science"](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring18/mcs.pdf), the discussion starts at page 1019. An (older) print version is available. No proof, though. Would need to slough through Leighton's [note](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/akrabazzi.pdf) to verify that the lecture notes/book version is right (it has somewhat different conditions, that are much easier to check).

Comment: This seems to be comment, not an answer? Am I missing something?

Comment: Shamelessly plugging my own work: I verified a variant of Leighton's version of the theorem in a proof assistant. There are some issues with Leighton's note, but if I recall correctly, the theorem itself was correct as stated. For details, see my paper: https://doi.org/10.1007/s10817-016-9378-0 Free preprint version available here: https://www21.in.tum.de/~eberlm/pdfs/divide_and_conquer_isabelle.pdf

Comment: Note that my version indeed requires the integral to exist on all compact intervals with sufficiently large boundaries, and it requires $g$ to be bounded on any such interval. These are very mild restrictions.

Comment: I recommend that paper of Manuel Eberl, *Proving Divide and Conquer Complexities in Isabelle/HOL*.